# SQL query to show most recent qty, but grouped by customer

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
Item Number   |   Customer   |   Creation Date   |   Onhand Qty   
  123               1              03-FEB-19            654
  234               3              03-FEB-19            987
  789               5              03-FEB-19            874
  321               4              03-FEB-19            147
  567               7              03-FEB-19            632
  123               1              29-JAN-19            547
  234               3              29-JAN-19            814
  789               5              29-JAN-19            458
  321               4              29-JAN-19            330
  567               7              29-JAN-19            118
```

I have this data set above, but for thousands of items and hundreds of customers.

What I'd like to do is to just return the latest 'Onhand Qty' field, so max(creation_date) but by item and customer.

```
    Item Number   |   Customer   |   Creation Date   |   Onhand Qty   
  123               1              03-FEB-19            654
  234               3              03-FEB-19            987
  789               5              03-FEB-19            874
  321               4              03-FEB-19            147
  567               7              03-FEB-19            632
```

Effectively, I'm trying to find the most recent onhand qty amount, by customer and item, so I can say that at the most recent check, 'Customer 1 had 654 units of Item 123'.

Is someone able to help me?

This is in an Oracle database (V11).

Many thanks

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (Having the above table data.)

Comment: Have amended.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer, Item_Number ORDER BY creation_date DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) WHERE rn = 1
```

In the subquery, `ROW_NUMBER()` assigns a sequence number to each record in groups of records having the same Customer/Item. The sequence is ordered by descending creation date (so the highest date comes first). Then, the outer query filters on the first record in each group.

This **[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=65603109d45a0b98a9d27dcad3f255ab)** with your sample data returns :

```
ITEM_NUMBER | CUSTOMER | CREATION_DATE | ONHAND_QTY | RN
----------: | -------: | :------------ | ---------: | -:
        123 |        1 | 29-JAN-19     |        547 |  1
        234 |        3 | 29-JAN-19     |        814 |  1
        321 |        4 | 29-JAN-19     |        330 |  1
        789 |        5 | 29-JAN-19     |        458 |  1
        567 |        7 | 29-JAN-19     |        118 |  1
```

Comment: Guys, you absolutely smashed it. THANKS! All the suggestions were similar, and it has worked really well. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from (select *,row_number() over(partition by Customer order by creation_date desc,qty desc) rn from table
) t where t.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using row_number() and add `partition by Customer,item order by creation_date desc` in over clause

```
select * from 
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by Customer,item order by creation_date desc) rn from table
)A where rn=1
```